# preload images in android

Tags: android, android-resources, image-preloader

I want to preload my game images while the splash screen. I'm loading all my sounds with SoundPool, but I didn't find something like this for images. How can I preload my images to use the resources later in the game. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just load them in `LruCache` as described in [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html#inBitmap)

Comment: Thanks this really helped me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623994/example-using-androids-lrucache